# Generic-type extension with a new generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, class-extensions

I'd like to extend the generic type `Array<Element>` with a constraint on `Element` that depends on another generic type, such as `Element == Optional<Wrapped>`.

In the case where `Element` is not generic, it is easy:

```swift
extension Array where Element == String {
    func merge() -> String { ... }
}
```

I tried the following, but the compiler does not accept it.

```swift
extension Array<Wrapped> where Element == Optional<Wrapped> {
    func merge() -> Optional<Wrapped> { ... }
}
```

What syntax should I use in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a constraint on the *method* instead:

```
extension Array {
    func merge<T>() -> T? where Element == T? {
        // ...
    }
}
```